# Linq Select Where IN

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Cannot find the lambda linq equivalent to `SELECT * FROM [Source] WHERE [Field] IN [String Array]`. I need to select all data from a data table that contains zip codes from a string array. I would like a faster way than just iterating through every row comparing them as I believe this would be fairly inefficient (or I believe it would anyway). I can't seem to find an adequate answer on Google of how to perform a lambda LINQ `IN` query on a data table. Any assistance would be great! Here is what I have currently:

```
List<string> lst = dtEtechZipCodeEmailRecipients.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(o => o.Field<string>("Email")).Distinct().ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count - 1; ++i)
{
    string email = lst[i].ToString().ToUpper();
    string[] zipCodes = dtEtechZipCodeEmailRecipients.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(zip => (zip.Field<string>("Email") ?? (object)String.Empty).ToString().ToUpper() == email)
        .Select(zip => zip.Field<string>("ZipCode")).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine(" - " + email);

    dtEtechModelRequests.AsEnumerable().Where(mod => mod.Field<string>("ZipCode").Contains(zipCodes)).Select(mod => mod);
}
```

That does not work, everything but the `.Contains` does do exactly what I need though. I left the `.Contains` to try and demonstrate my point.

Comment: So you want to know if a list of all zip codes is contained in a single zip code.  Does that make sense?  Will all of those zip codes ever exist inside of the one zip code that you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do opposite thing - check whether array of zip codes contains current zip code:

```
Where(mod => zipCodes.Contains(mod.Field<string>("ZipCode"))
```

That is same as verifying if current zip code IN array.

Comment: Okay, so now what if the result it null? This throws an error. `List<DataRow> l = dtEtechModelRequests.AsEnumerable().Where(mod => zipCodes.Contains(mod.Field<string>("ZipCode"))).ToList();`

Comment: @Volearix which result is null? `zipCodes` cannot be null. What error your have?

Comment: `{"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"}` Is the exact error I receive.

Comment: @Volearix make sure `dtEtechModelRequests` is not null. Use debugger to break on this line and check values of variables

Comment: Duh, that was the issue. My code was in a 'debug' mode which doesn't run the procedures to fill the data tables. Thank you for the correct answer as well as the 'troubleshooting'!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your question is,

```
[Source].Where(el => [String Array].Contains(el.Field<string>("Field"))
```

And if you need `NOT IN` then follow the following pattern

**Adding `!` infront of your `[String Array]`**

```
[Source].Where(el => ![String Array].Contains(el.Field<string>("Field"))
```

**alternative representation**

```
[Source].Where(el => [String Array].Contains(el.Field<string>("Field")==false)
```